# Is it possible to filter out duplicate rows using the QUERY() function only and how?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I receive answers via a Google Forms, which I want to put in a pivot QUERY. I made a query that does the job for all rows, but in the case of duplicate answers, I only want to include rows with the same values in column A, B, and C once.

Here is a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pe-6GdLzclN1oUH_VK9tgtNLfaFjF1wQX8QwzAhAGgo/edit?usp=sharing) with the data in the `Data` sheet, my query in the `What I have` sheet:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:E, "SELECT C, SUM(D) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY C PIVOT A",-1)
```

and what I am asking for in the `What I need` sheet.

Comment: After seeing pnuts answer, I now realise that MAX (or MIN) is the aggregation function that I need and not SUM.  I do not understand your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAX instead of SUM should work (at least for your example!).

Comment: Wow, that makes me feel stupid! :D
Then using MIN would also be a solution :)